JVM Memory Tuning to utilize server memory
We have a AWS EC2 instance (t3.xlarge which has 16GB of memory) 64 bit (x86_64 GNU/Linux). With Java11. It is logging the following error:
ERROR 10:47:09.326 std.err - Memory: 8555069440 of: 34324873216
ERROR 10:47:09.326 std.err - Thread count: 976
ERROR 10:47:09.326 std.err - IO TPI: 6776.744165170557 TPO: 7549.293 IOR: 1.1139999999999999 QSZ: 37 THROTTLE: 0

So I think I need to tune the JVM memory to allow it to use the available 16B of memory (seems to be limited to 8GB).
The following shows me that the old gen memory in the JVM is currently 8GB, (i.e. concurrent mark-sweep generation total 8047872K), where 941 is the PID of the application running on port 8080.
jcmd 941 GC.heap_info
941:
 par new generation   total 306688K, used 215304K [0x00007fb2c8000000, 0x00007fb2dccc0000, 0x00007fb2dccc0000)
  eden space 272640K,  76% used [0x00007fb2c8000000, 0x00007fb2d4bf7738, 0x00007fb2d8a40000)
  from space 34048K,  18% used [0x00007fb2d8a40000, 0x00007fb2d908aa60, 0x00007fb2dab80000)
  to   space 34048K,   0% used [0x00007fb2dab80000, 0x00007fb2dab80000, 0x00007fb2dccc0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 8047872K, used 2223911K [0x00007fb2dccc0000, 0x00007fb4c8000000, 0x00007fbac8000000)
 Metaspace       used 223752K, capacity 235070K, committed 235164K, reserved 235520K

Question
Should I use the JAVA_OPTS to set the old gen memory?
e.g.
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"

What values should I set?

Java memory settings for you application is not something that others should be recommending. You can test different values and see what's better for you. And don't try to use the entire physical memory for the Java heap. There would not be space for the operating system and the rest of the memory used by Java. And where do you see those 'errors'? They don't seem to be Java generated. And what version of the JVM are you using? Permgen was replaced in Java 8. No current version of Java uses it.

According to the jcmd output "total 8047872K, used 2223911K" your application only uses about 2GB of heap memory. Just increasing the max heap size will not increase the amount of memory your applications uses.

Yes, you can use the JAVA_OPTS environment variable to set the JVM memory parameters. Based on the information you provided, you can adjust the JAVA_OPTS to allocate more memory to the old generation space. Here's how you can modify it:
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8g -Xmx16g -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"

Explanation of the parameters:

Xms8g: Sets the initial heap size to 8 GB.
Xmx16g: Sets the maximum heap size to 16 GB.
XX:NewSize=256m: Sets the initial size of the young generation (eden + two survivor spaces) to 256 MB.
XX:MaxNewSize=356m: Sets the maximum size of the young generation to 356 MB.
XX:PermSize=256m: Sets the initial size of the permanent generation (Metaspace in Java 8 and later) to 256 MB.
XX:MaxPermSize=356m: Sets the maximum size of the permanent generation to 356 MB.

These values may need to be adjusted based on your application's memory requirements and usage patterns. Additionally, make sure your application is compatible with these settings and monitor its performance to ensure it behaves as expected.

Thanks @Dilshan, I will give it a try.

Unfortunately after export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8g -Xmx16g -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m" then restarting the application server, the values are still the same when I run jcmd 17764 GC.heap_info. They don't seem to have updated.

It is a bad idea to use all the memory for the heap. There would not be enough memory for the system and even other Java memory pools.
